# How to solve HTTP Status 500 - org/glassfish/jersey/servlet/ServletContainer error in eclipse (apache tomcat)

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets, glassfish

```
HTTP Status 500 - org/glassfish/jersey/servlet/ServletContainer : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer)
type Exception report

message org/glassfish/jersey/servlet/ServletContainer : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer)

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/glassfish/jersey/servlet/ServletContainer : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2922)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1174)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1669)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:491)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.47 logs.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
```

I tried restarting the server... And also adding and removing the project.. but it is of no use... pls help me here..

I already tried everything in this link related to eclipse
[How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0-error)

My problem is still not solved

Comment: What JDK version do you use to run Tomcat?

Comment: Am using java 1.6 and  tomcat v7.0

Comment: You need to run on Java 7. Like the duplicate link indicates, the version of Jersey you're running for your servlet container needs Java 7 (version 51.0) to run properly. You're using Java 6 (version 50.0), which is too low.